# how to add an dll references into an c# yeoman project?

Tags: c#, yeoman

I'm new to yeoman. I got the file "MySql.Data.dll" to connect to wamp server mysql, how do I add an references to that dll files? I've tried searching for the answer on google but I can't find the answer. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Which yeoman generator you have used?

Comment: only aspnet. nothing else.